# Checking a class type (.class) is equal to some other class type

Tags: java, reflection

Is the following code valid?

```
void myMethod (Class classType) {
   if (classType == MyClass.class) {
       // do something
   }
}

myMethod (OtherClass.class);
```

If not is there any other approach where I can check if a passed .class (Class Type) is of type - MyClass ?

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers or comment if the answers are not meeting your requirements Fahim. Jon's answer is impeccable (as usual).

Answer (score 58):

Yes, that code is valid - if the two classes have been loaded by the same classloader. If you want the two classes to be treated as equal even if they've been loaded by *different* classloaders, possibly from different locations, based on the fully-qualified name, then just compare fully-qualified names instead.

Note that your code only considers an *exact* match, however - it won't provide the sort of "assignment compatibility" that (say) `instanceof` does when seeing whether a value refers to an object which is an instance of a given class. For that, you'd want to look at `Class.isAssignableFrom`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd rather compare the canonical names to be completely sure, classType.getCanonicalName().equals(MyClass.class.getCanonicalName()).

Note that this may bring issues with anonymous and inner classes, if you are using them you may consider using getName instead.

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me:

```
public class Test {

    void myMethod(Class classType) {
        System.out.println(classType.isAssignableFrom(Test.class));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.myMethod(String.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `instanceof`.

```
Animal a = new Tiger();
System.out.println(a instanceof Tiger); // true
System.out.println(a instanceof Animal); //true
```

Alternatively you could compare two classes with

```
a.getClass() == b.getClass()
```

Comment: `instanceof` returns `true` also for subclasses, which probably is not what OP wants

Comment: The question was about comparing the actual classes, not comparing objects.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 
`classType.getCanonicalName().equals(MyClass.class.getCanonicalName())`
the above will not consider any generics (all map are the same, all set are the same etc)