# Checking if an object matches a list of known types

Tags: java

Below is a pseudo-code of what I want to achieve, in mostly complete/usable java.

An exception is thrown, and I want to check it against a list of known exception types without having to do a long series of if-checks to see if it is *instanceof* each type

```java
//pretend this is the exception that was thrown
Exception e = new CustomException2();

//I want to have a set of expected types
Set<Type> expectedExceptionTypes = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(CustomException1, CustomException2, CustomException3));

//I want to see which type the exception matches to or else give a default (UnknownException)
Optional<Type> type = expectedExceptionTypes.stream().filter((t) -> e instanceof t).findFirst().orElse(UnknownException);

//... perform some action based on the exception type
```

How can I actually implement something like this? Am I on the right track here?

What I'm trying to avoid:

```java
if(e instanceof CustomException1)
    ...
if(e instanceof CustomException2)
    ...
if(e instanceof CustomException3)
    ...
.
.
.
```

Comment: Look at `Class.isAssignableFrom`, as `instanceof` needs a literal parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pattern called `Chain of Responsibility` that can be used to achieve what you want. It can have different forms, you're on the right track. What you need is change `expectedExceptionTypes` to hold the condition you're checking against and also the code to handle it. For example, define a class that packs those two together:

```
class ExceptionHandler {
    Predicate<Exception> condition;
    Consumer<Exception> handlingCode;

    public ExceptionHandler(Predicate<Exception> condition, Consumer<Exception> handlingCode) {
        this.condition = condition;
        this.handlingCode = handlingCode;
    }
}
```

Then is just finding the first handler that satisfies the condition, and call it:

```
final Set<ExceptionHandler> handlers = new HashSet<>(
        Arrays.asList(
                new ExceptionHandler(
                        v -> v instanceof CustomException1,
                        t -> System.out.println("Handling exception of type: " + t)
                ),
                new ExceptionHandler(
                        v -> v instanceof CustomException2,
                        t -> System.out.println("Handling exception of type: " + t
                        )))
);

handlers.stream().filter((ExceptionHandler t) -> t.condition.test(e))
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(exceptionHandler -> exceptionHandler.handlingCode.accept(e));
```

Note I explicitly use `instanceof` inline, to avoid the type erasure problems, but any method that works can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can bit modify your code by using [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instead of [Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) and comparing by `Objects.equals(t.getCanonicalName(), e.getClass().getCanonicalName())`(or `e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(t)` explanation below):

```java
Exception e = new CustomException2();

Set<Class> expectedExceptionTypes = new HashSet<>(Arrays
        .asList(CustomException1.class, CustomException2.class, , CustomException3.class));
   
// get type the exception matches to or else have a default UnknownException.class     
Class type = expectedExceptionTypes
        .stream()
        .filter( t -> Objects.equals(t.getCanonicalName(), e.getClass().getCanonicalName()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(UnknownException.class);

//... perform some action based on the exception type
```

Use `e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(t)` instead of  `Objects.equals(t.getCanonicalName(), e.getClass().getCanonicalName())` if you don't want "exact match" (for more info [Checking a class type (.class) is equal to some other class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850951/checking-a-class-type-class-is-equal-to-some-other-class-type))

Answer (score 1):

Store the *classes* in the Set and use `contains(e.getClass())`.

Define your target classes (probably as `static final` constant):

```
Set<Class<?>> exceptionClasses = Set.of(CustomException1.class, CustomException2.class, CustomException3class); // since Java 9
```

Then given

```
Exception e = someException;

e = exceptionClasses.contains(e.getClass()) ? e : new UnknownException();
```